# How to limit serializing in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 serializers that add and subtract (they are the same, with the difference being add +=1 and subtract -=1) points to an answer. I want to limit them so that a user can only use add point to an answer once. Do you have any idea how to get to it in Django Rest Framework?

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    number_of_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

```
class SubtractPointsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('number_of_points',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        instance.number_of_points -= 1
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/answers/2/addpoints
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 226, in put
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 68, in update
    self.perform_update(serializer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 78, in perform_update
    serializer.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 200, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/Users/jakubstrawa/programming/gitlabdeor/api/questions/serializers.py", line 74, in update
    if not instance.addition_done and self.request.user not in instance.voters.all():
AttributeError: 'AddPointsSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a `Boolean` field that stores if addition/subtraction was done. You can store every `User` that had voted already so noone will vote twice (also will not vote for both +1/-1).

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    number_of_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    addition_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subtraction_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField('User', default=None, blank=True)

===========================================================

class SubtractPointsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if not instance.subtraction_done:
            instance.number_of_points -= 1
            instance.subtraction_done = True
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

You can also divide `ManyToMany` field into two separated (one for addition, another for subtraction).

Comment: But i think that this way, if lets say user A likes an answer and it makes addition_done = True, then noone else can upvote this answer, because it has addition_done = True in model.

Comment: Gimme a sec and I will edit with `ManyToMany` field.

Comment: I've added `ManyToMany` field, but I am not 100% sure how you handle `User` model, so you might need to reconfigure it a little bit. I hope you can manage from now on.

Comment: Hey! I tried the code, and it says that AttributeError: 'AddPointsSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'. Copied the traceback in the post. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, then `self.request` does not work in `Serializers` like that. I have to ask then, why do you want it do be done here? It looks like it should be handled in `views`, not `serializers`. You are not supposed to fetch current `User` here.

Comment: Well actually i didn't know that, im very new to DRF. It can be taken to views.py

Comment: `Serializers` should moslty manage only changing data types from database-like to JSON/dict and vice-versa. All the other managing should be somewhere else or you will be lost at some point. You probably don't need them if you create simple app. At least not at this point I believe.